# How can you make the cards for ant.design smaller?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using the ant.design `Card` component to display the messages for a chat webapp in react/redux. Right now each card gives too much space around the card. Is there anyway to make the card wrap the text closer?

[image]

Where the React code is:

```
                        <Card
                            bordered={false}
                            style={{
                                // other styles...
                                width: width,
                                height: 70 <== just decreasing this number doesn't work 
                            }}
                        >
                            <p>{message.contents}</p>
                        </Card>
```

Just decreasing the height doesn't work and produces:

[image]

Comment: Does <p> paragraph has margin around it? If yes, can you remove that?

Comment: @user6297534 thanks for the idea but <p/> has no margin around it

Comment: Any `padding` and/or `line-height` styles at play?

Comment: @NateWhittaker not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I would inspect the element in the dev tools first, but more than likely, you should set the height of the card to 'auto' and add padding to the text inside. Putting a class on the p tag:

`<p class='message-contents'>{message.contents}</p>`

and targeting it:

`.message-contents {
padding: 20px;
}`

will set the space inside of the card to 20px on each side of the text. Change this to what you want.

Also I suggest using a class on the card also and putting all styling in an external stylesheet, but either works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gutter property of Row as grid spacing, we recommend set it to (16 + 8n) px. (n stands for natural number.)

You can set it to a object like **{ xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }** for responsive design.

You can use a array to set vertical spacing, **[horizontal, vertical] [16, { xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }].**

https://ant.design/components/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Card`s I just used a regular `p` tag with `borderRadius` and `padding`:

```
                    <p
                        style={{

                            borderRadius: '25px',
                            padding: '4px 15px 4px'
                        }}
                    >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inline style property `bodyStyle` to apply styles to the card content.

The better way to keep your components clean use `css`.

```
  <Card className="custom-card" bordered={false}>
    <p>Hey Hunter</p>
  </Card>
```

css:

```
.custom-card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}

.custom-card > .ant-card-body {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.custom-card > .ant-card-body > p {
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell; 
}
```

Check the **[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/pkyw6qn5xj)**.